# Inheritance in protobuf.net, adding a lower base class still backward compatible?

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have been using protobuf.net for a while and it is excellent. I can have a class which is inherited from a base class, I can serialise the derived class by using ProtoInclude statements in the base class. If my base class originally had only say two ProtoInclude statements when the object was serialised, say

```
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(Vol_SurfaceObject))]
[ProtoInclude(200, typeof(CurveObject))]
internal abstract class MarketDataObject
```

I can still deserialise that same object in to code that has evolved to have more derivations:

```
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(Vol_SurfaceObject))]
[ProtoInclude(200, typeof(CurveObject))]
[ProtoInclude(300, typeof(StaticDataObject))]
internal abstract class MarketDataObject
```

So far so good (in fact excellent, thanks Marc). However, now what if I want to have a base class even lower then my current base class here (in this case,  MarketDataObject). Such that I would have

```
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(Vol_SurfaceObject))]
[ProtoInclude(200, typeof(CurveObject))]
[ProtoInclude(300, typeof(StaticDataObject))]
internal abstract class MarketDataObject : LowerStillBaseClass
{ blah }

[ProtoInclude(10, typeof(MarketDataObject))]
internal abstract class LowerStillBaseClass
{ blah }
```

Whilst the code will of course work, will I be still be able to deserialise the initial objects that were serialised when the object had only 2 ProtoInclude statements to this new form of the MarketDataObject class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work purely with static protbuf-net attributes.  Simplifying somewhat, imagine you start with the following :

```
namespace V1
{
    [ProtoContract]
    internal class MarketDataObject
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And refactor it to be the following:

```
namespace V2
{
    [ProtoInclude(10, typeof(MarketDataObject))]
    [ProtoContract]
    internal abstract class LowerStillBaseClass
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string LowerStillBaseClassProperty { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    internal class MarketDataObject : LowerStillBaseClass
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Next, try to deserialize a created from the V1 class into a V2 class.  You will fail with the following exception:

> ```
> ProtoBuf.ProtoException: No parameterless constructor found for LowerStillBaseClass
> ```

**The reason** this does not work is that type hierarchies are serialized base-first rather than derived-first.  To see this, dump the protobuf-net contracts for each type by calling `Console.WriteLine(RuntimeTypeModel.Default.GetSchema(type));`  For `V1.MarketDataObject` we get:

```
message MarketDataObject {
   optional string Id = 1;
}
```

And for `V2.MarketDataObject`:

```
message LowerStillBaseClass {
   optional string LowerStillBaseClassProperty = 1;
   // the following represent sub-types; at most 1 should have a value
   optional MarketDataObject MarketDataObject = 10;
}
message MarketDataObject {
   optional string Id = 1;
}
```

`MarketDataObject` is getting encoded into a [message](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) with its base type fields first, at the top level, then derived type fields are recursively encapsulated inside a nested optional message with a field id that represents its subtype.  So when a V1 message is deserialized to a V2 object, no subtype field is encountered, the correct derived type is not inferred, and derived type values are lost.

**One workaround** is to avoid using `[ProtoInclude(10, typeof(MarketDataObject))]` and instead populate the base class members in the derived type's contract programmatically using the [`RuntimeTypeModel` API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/642677/Protobuf-net-the-unofficial-manual#without):

```
namespace V3
{
    [ProtoContract]
    internal abstract class LowerStillBaseClass
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string LowerStillBaseClassProperty { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    internal class MarketDataObject : LowerStillBaseClass
    {
        static MarketDataObject()
        {
            AddBaseTypeProtoMembers(RuntimeTypeModel.Default);
        }

        const int BaseTypeIncrement = 11000;

        public static void AddBaseTypeProtoMembers(RuntimeTypeModel runtimeTypeModel)
        {
            var myType = runtimeTypeModel[typeof(MarketDataObject)];
            var baseType = runtimeTypeModel[typeof(MarketDataObject).BaseType];
            if (!baseType.GetSubtypes().Any(s => s.DerivedType == myType))
            {
                foreach (var field in baseType.GetFields())
                {
                    myType.Add(field.FieldNumber + BaseTypeIncrement, field.Name);
                }
            }
        }

        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(Here I am populating the contract inside the static constructor for `MarketDataObject`.  You might want to do it elsewhere.)  The schema for `V3.` looks like:

```
message MarketDataObject {
   optional string Id = 1;
   optional string LowerStillBaseClassProperty = 11001;
}
```

This schema is compatible with the V1 schema, and so A V1 message can be deserialized into a V3 class without data loss.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rrSPDQ).

Of course, if you are moving a member from `MarketDataObject` to `LowerStillBaseClass` you will need to ensure that the field id stays the same.

The disadvantage of this workaround is that you lose the ability to deserialize an object of type `LowerStillBaseClass` and have protobuf-net automatically infer the correct derived type.

Comment: Thanks for you very detailed answer and the time it must have taken you. It makes perfect sense what you are saying.